# Rename these files with wired names

Tags: bash

I have many files named
001ac.jpg  002ae.jpg 003.ag.jpg ... 012gf.jpg
I need to change them to 
001.jpg 002.jpg 003.jpg 004.jpg....012.jpg

i have some solutions now, but i think they are wired too. So any other good solutions?

now i have this:

```
#!/bin/sh    
rename .jpg .89 *    
for i in {a..z}    do
rename $i '' *.jpg
rename $i '' *.jpg    
 done    
rename .89 .jpg *
```

and this:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 for i in `find . -name "*.jpg"`
  4     do
  5         j=${i:0:5}
  6         echo $j
  7         mv $i $j.jpg
  8 done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, I would use your loop to explcitily remove just the chars from the filename, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( find . -name "*.jpg") ;do
      new=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/[A-Za-z\.][A-Za-z\.]*//g')           
      echo $new
      echo mv $i $new.jpg
done
```

Remove the `echo` in front of `mv` when you are satisfied this is working as needed. Any spaces in filenames will mess things up, might want to add `-printf0` at the end of your fine command.

Also, Don't use backquotes for cmd-substitution. They've been deprecated at least since 1995 ;-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's lack of another [A-Za-z\.] in sed. Isn't it? If you use just two ,it can be zero with *.

Comment: Hmmm I not sure of your point. Yes, only /[A-Za-z\.]*/ can be a zero length match and is useless. That is why I put 2 series of [A-ZA-Z\.] in the sed match pattern. Did either of these solutions work for you? If so please accept an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 find . -name "*.jpg" | 
 sed -n  's|^\(\./[0-9]\+\)\([^0-9]\+\)\(\.jpg\)$|mv -v & \1\3|p' | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite comprehend the first solution. I don't know of a `rename` command.

The second solution might be good if you can guarantee the exact format of the name, but why do you have the length as 5 in `${i:0:5}` instead of 3? The examples you gave all have a number length of 3 digits. And, if you're doing a find, you shouldn't put it in a for loop. Just pipe it into a a `read`:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" | while read $name
do
    newName=${name:0:3}
    mv $name $newName.jpg
done
```

Here's another possible solution. It simply loops through all of your numbers. The `printf` formats the number to be zero filled and three digits. The if makes sure the file exists before you try to rename it.

```
for number in {1..100}
do
   zf_number=$(printf "%03d", $number)   #Zero fill number
   if [ -e ${zf_number}* ]
   then 
       mv ${zf_number}* $zf_number.jpg
   fi
done
```

That will go sequentially through all the files in the directory and rename them. The `printf` zero fills the number to match the name on the files.

---

> Because find gives filenames like this: ./001 ./002 ./003

You're right. However, you're probably better off removing the directory and basename of the file, then putting them back together. That way, you don't have issues if some of the files are in sub-directories.

```
find . -name "*.jpg" | while read $name
do
    dirname=$(dirname $name)
    basename=$(basename $name)
    newName=${basename:0:3}
    mv "$dirname/$basename" "$dirname/$newname.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Because find gives filenames like this: ./001 ./002 ./003

Comment: To zero-fill the number, you want `printf "%03d" $number` with no comma

Comment: @glenn jackman You're right. I forgot the zero in front. I'll edit and fix my post.

Comment: @apporc - Okay, I see. You're right. However, you're probably better off separating the base and directory names, then putting them back together. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

[numerate.sh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numerate/files/numerate.sh/download)

This code snipped should do the job:

```
./numerate.sh -d <your image folder> -b <start number> -L 3 -s .jpg -o numerically -r
```